# Deriving inequalities for exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I'm trying to derive the following two inequalities for the exponential function, where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$, $t>0$ and $a>1$
$$
|y-z|e^{-\frac{(y-z)^2}{2at}}\leq\; C_at^\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{(y-z)^2}{4at}},\\
t^{-\frac{1}{a}}|y-z|^{1+\frac{2}{a}}e^{-\frac{(y-z)^2}{2at}}\leq \; C_at^\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{(y-z)^2}{4at}},
$$
with some constant $C_a>0$

I  tried to derive it by using derivatives but it didn't work for  the purpose. I'm grateful for any advice on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{|y-z|}{t^{1/2}}e^{-{(y-z)^2}/{2at}}\leq\; C_ae^{-{(y-z)^2}/{4at}}$$

is

$$ue^{-u^2/2a}\le C_ae^{-u^2/4a}$$

or
$$ue^{-u^2/4a}\le C_a.$$

The second case is similar.